# Making parallel API calls while reading a file(csv)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, csv, parallel-processing

I have very specific requirement and I don't have any clue how to start with. I am new to c# so please bear with rather vague question:

I need to read a csv file and for each entry make an web API call. What I want is this:

1. Read one entry(row) of csv file.
2. Make API call and store response in DB
3. While 2 is going on, keep reading and buffering CSV entries. If possible, while DB is being written to, keep making API calls

Can someone please point me to the way this can be achieved? I am working on C#,.NET
Note: Please feel free to take any example csv, API call etc.

Comment: The csv is being written to while you read?

Comment: @I3arnon No CSV is pre-written and hence won't change. I need to read it, call api for each row and save response on DB.

Comment: Then my answer fits. Although if the file is **way** too big (several gigs) as @Rasher suggested you would replace `File.ReadAllLines` with a dynamic loop that reads a single row in every iteration.

Comment: @I3arnon I think my file will not exceed 50 MB or so.

Comment: Then stick with ReadAllLines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general answer for a general question:

1. `File.ReadAllLines` gets all rows off a file. `String.Split` gets all cells of a row.
2. `Parallel.Foreach` will go through the rows in parallel (on a multi-core environment).
3. It seems you want the calls to the DB to be asynchronous. You can achieve this using `async-await` but only if your specific database client supports async calls.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on size csv files. If you can load it to memory via File.ReadAllLines then scenario provided by @i3arnon make good point. You can also check this url:
[Make an Async/Await db call within a Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769189/make-an-async-await-db-call-within-a-task)

Comment: CSV has around 40-50k lines